# Microsoft Azure BizTalk Services deployment registration has failed

Tags: azure, service, biztalk

When I try to register my BizTalk service, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft Azure BizTalk Services deployment registration has failed. 
Registration has failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Azure Active Directory integration on BizTalk Portal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinaysingh/archive/2014/10/06/azure-active-directory-integration-on-biztalk-portal.aspx)

> **Gotchas**
>
> Microsoft account and Organizational accounts cannot manage same BizTalk Service - A BizTalk Service can be either associated with Microsoft accounts or Organizational accounts. Therefore, all user accounts managing a particular BizTalk Service should either be  Microsoft accounts or Organizational accounts.
>   Users from different organizations cannot manage same BizTalk Service - A BizTalk Service can be associated with only one organization. Therefore, all organzational users accounts managing a particular BizTalk Service should belong to the same organization.
>   You will get following error on the register account page in either of the cases mentioned above -
>
> **Microsoft Azure BizTalk Services deployment registration has failed.**
>
> **Registration has failed..**